# Google Cloud http load balancer SSL termination

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have an instance listening on port 8080.

I want to create a load balancer to map 443 (ssl) to the instance port 8080 so that ssl terminates at the load balancer and traffic between the lb and the instance is not encrypted.

I have uploaded the ssl cert, created an HTTP load balancer but can't seem to figure out how to set up the forwarding like that.

Coming from AWS ELB, there's a simple way to do this, can't find a way to do it on Google Cloud Platform.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 6):

Found it.

1. Create an instance group that has at least 1 live instance
2. Create http load balancer with the following:

   1. Upload a SSL certificate
   2. Create a backend service to point to the instance group. Make sure the protocol is HTTP
   3. Create a target https proxy with the certificate you uploaded
   4. Finally, create a global forwarding rule that points HTTPS to the target proxy you created before.